# Anyone using Aegir to manage sites?

Tags: civicrm-home, drupal-8, aegir

Not really a Civi specific question but someone here might have suggestions on the best place to discuss.

Got the basics working.  Now I need to figure out how to best add in or update modules and themes

Comment: Glad it just worked!  One of the lead Aegir shops has an associated CiviCRM consultancy, so Aegir has a `provision_civicrm` module built in.

Comment: Should I be doing anything specific Jon?  I just include the civi modules in my composer.json and enable the module after it is all provisioned up.

Comment: I'm not sure - I don't use Aegir myself!

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely folks using Aegir with Drupal 8/CiviCRM, and more using Drupal 7/CiviCRM.  You can connect with them on https://chat.civicrm.org in the ~sysadmin channel.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I'll bookmark that. As for the original question... wow, it just worked! I made the platform with the appropriate modules and when I instantiated a site, poof, enabling the module and it just worked. Color me 'impressed.'